# jQuery .width() function issue with php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

In calling an $("element").width() inside a $(document).ready function, I have found that I am getting varying answers.

I believe this has something to do with session variable checking. If I have code like this:

```
<body>  
    <?php
    if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){?>
        <!-- HTML Code Here -->
        <div id="some_element"> </div>
        <!-- End HTML Code -->
    <?php
    }
    else { ?>
        <!-- More HTML Code -->
```

And I reference "some_element" using:

```
$(document.ready(function(){
   alert($("#some_element").width());
});
```

Will I be guaranteed a distinct value to be returned for the width, if I have CSS that looks like this:

```
#some_element
{
   width:300px;
}
```

In testing, it seems like the return value I get actually does vary. If nesting the HTML code inside the PHP if statement is what is causing the issue, is there some other, better method to do so? I was thinking that the $(document).ready() method would wait until all the html was loaded so I could access those DOM objects.

Also, the issue with having variable values returned from .width() is occurring in Chrome.
Firefox seems to work fine and in IE the entire page looks messed up (this might be due to other code, not sure though).

Any help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT:** Here is the solution (not for IE, still have no idea what's up going on with that) I have come up with for now. Inside both PHP if statements, I place a  tag along with an onload attribute set to the function. In this case it would like something like:

```
<?php
    if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){?>
    <body onload="helperFunction()">
         <div id="some_element"> </div>
```

If this is bad practice, or if there is a better way to achieve this kind of functionality, I'd appreciate the insight. Thanks for the quick replies guys.

Comment: jquery has nothing to do with PHP and especially with session variables. Post here HTML code you have issues with

Comment: try using the !important property in css, like 
  ` width:300px !important;` may be this will help in overwriting the previous css property

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: I think that was part of the question. In the conditional PHP statement above (if the 'username' session variable is set), it will display the following html elements - in this case the "some_element" div.
My question was regarding jQuery's .width() function and how using that conditional might affect its return value.

Comment: if you have issues with 2 different HTML blocks - it is issues with 2 different HTML blocks, not with PHP variables. See?

Comment: @June Tried it, but to no avail :/. Thanks, though

Answer (score 0):

Quoted from [`.width`](http://api.jquery.com/width/)

> Note that in modern browsers, the CSS width property does not include
>   padding, border, or margin, unless the [**`box-sizing`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/Box-sizing) CSS property is
>   used.

Comment: I think all I need is the regular width property.

Answer (score 0):

A non-styled element with `display: block` and `position: static` will span across the entire inner width of its parent. If the parent of that `<div>` is the document body, as in your snippet, then that `<div>` will have the width of the browser window (sans margin/border/padding of the `<body>` element, if any).

Specifying width explicitly should produce more consistent results.

What are you trying to accomplish, anyway?

Comment: Actually this was just an example. The actual issue is with a div nested in a position:relative parent div.

Comment: In a nutshell, I want to place this slidechanger inside some existing code I have that checks whether a user is logged in or not. If the user is not logged in yet, show the slide show, among other things, otherwise show some other elements. The buttons for the slide changer are the things I'm having issues with - I'm trying to place them inside a parent toolbar, but when I nest them inside that PHP conditional, I'm not guaranteed a .width() value - I use that .width() value to calculate where I want to place them.

Comment: I think it has nothing to do with PHP. If you always display that div, do you get consistent widths?

Comment: I do, though I am not sure how the visibility:hidden property would affect the outcome.

Comment: From my experience, it is better to avoid visibility altogether. That experience dates back to IE6 though. :)

Comment: Yeah, I'm not using visibility at all. Just brought it up since you mentioned "displaying" the div, and using visibility is another way to undisplay one.